Java 1Password CLI Integration Not working in the server
I'm integrating 1Password CLI commands in the java application. I have to authenticate to the 1Password using Add Account command. This command is an interactive command, where I have to type-in the password in the terminal.
While I execute this in my linux server, I see an error while my app typing the password.
Error: inappropriate ioctl for device
    String command = "op account add --address <domain> --email <email> --signin --raw";
    var processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    processBuilder.directory(new File("/usr/local/bin"));
    processBuilder.inheritIO();

    Map<String,String> environment = processBuilder.environment();
    environment.put("OP_SECRET_KEY", configuration.getOnePasswordSecretKey());
    environment.put("PWD", configuration.getOnePasswordPassword());

    processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);

    processBuilder.start();

How to get this resolved?
I tried using expect script to execute the interactive script, but that too didn't work. While executing the script the command is not prompting for the password entry.
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout -1
op account add --address myDomain.1password.com --email ranjith.aruchamy@1password.com --raw --signin

expect "Enter the Secret Key for"
send "$env(OP_SECRET_KEY)\r"

expect "Enter the password for"
send "$env(PWD)\r"

interact



Try this: List<String> command = List.of("op", "account", "add", "--address <domain>", "--email <email>", "--signin", "--raw"); var processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
